# Upgrade instance type from r4 to r5 in AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using currently an r4 instance.

```
Model       vCPU    Mem (GiB)   Storage     Networking Performance (Gbps)
r4.4xlarge  16      122         EBS-Only    Up to 10
```

And I am planning to upgrade to r5 (almost with same configuration)

```
Model       vCPU    Mem (GiB)   Storage     Networking Performance (Gbps)
r5.4xlarge  16      128         EBS-Only    3,500   Up to 10
```

I could see here, only RAM changes, however the Storage type still remains same. So there won't be any surprises (in terms of any issues)

What would have happened after the upgrade the db instance to r5

1. My db endpoint will change?
2. If I had custom location for my temp file generation, will it impact anything after the upgrade?
3. Bottom of the line, there will be any change in storage after updating to r5?

If I use one of r5d* instance type, Do I have complete control on storage, not like EBS (I don't have any visibility / control on this)?

Answer (score 1):

Storage and Compute are handled separately in Amazon RDS. So, changing Instance Type will not impact **storage**.

The **DNS Name** associated with the db instance will not change.

From [Amazon EC2 Instance Types - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/):

> With M5d instances, local NVMe-based SSDs are physically connected to the host server and provide block-level storage that is coupled to the lifetime of the M5 instance

These disks are "Instance Store" that disappear when the M5 instance is stopped/terminated. Therefore, the database cannot use them because the storage is not persistent. Thus, it appears you can't use `m5d` with Amazon RDS.